# Why is it called “tossing” a salad? (in cooking)

Tags: etymology, verbs

…instead of just “mixing” it?

I googled, but the results basically all point to sex, whereas I mean mixing together the vegetable ingredients in a salad.

Thanks!

Comment: I googled "toss a/the salad" And...horrors I had no idea. So, look up ["**toss**"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toss) in a dictionary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Lol, I'm so sorry

Comment: [gif of someone tossing a salad](https://media4.giphy.com/media/VzxbGD7OePK5rtglDc/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e4726ieekb42mhtk0932l4i8moxnnkyrqtizr7ty09l&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g) Safe for work

Comment: A "tossed salad" is a salad where you mix the ingredients by (sort of) tossing them in the air.

Comment: ... and to spread the dressing evenly. You would not want to *stir* it - that could cause mechanical damage to the ingredients.

Comment: In Britain, you don't want people to say you are a 'tosser'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I am very and profoundly sorry…

Comment: You might add "in cooking" to the title for clarification.

Comment: Could we please get off the UD shtick? "Tossed salad" is used a lot on American menus. Obviously it means something else to BrE users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Mix" is generally used when the result is in a state where it is impossible (or nearly so) to separate back into the component parts.

Once you mix cake batter, you can't turn it back into eggs, flour and milk.  Once you mix a screwdriver, you can't separate it back into orange juice and tequila.

Comment: OK, but why “toss”? What is the etymology of “toss” in this context?
(And please don’t talk about alcohol; it’s making me want to drink—to forget the question!)

Comment: Because that is literally what you are doing.  You take two salad serving spoons and gently toss the ingredients into the air

Comment: Thank you! I’m French-speaking, as you can guess by my name, but I dated mostly English-speaking women, and spent 9 of the past 11 years with an English speaker… Even though my “cooking” knowledge was slim to none when we met, she never explained to me that you’re supposed to “toss the ingredients into the air,” and I was just “mixing” them—I guess she never saw what I was doing! Thank you for clarifying! :)

Comment: Hard salad ingredients could take mixing with a bit of vigor. Leafy lettuce would actually be harmed by the rough blending. A lighter touch of lifting, not mashing, works better. Tossing salad is similar to folding rather than stirring airy cake batters that have beaten egg whites.